# Equivalent determinant condition for Peres-Horodecki criteria

Tags: entanglement, mathematics, density-matrix, matrix-representation, partial-transpose

The Peres-Horodecki criteria for a 2*2 state states that if the smallest eigenvalue of the partial transpose of the state is negative, it is entangled, else it is separable.

According to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4397) (page 4, left side), the following is an equivalent formulation to express the above criterion.

Assume the matrix in question looks like this:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\rho_{00,00} & \rho_{00,01} & \rho_{00,10} & \rho_{00,11} \\
\rho_{01,00} & \rho_{01,01} & \rho_{01,10} & \rho_{01,11} \\
\rho_{10,00} & \rho_{10,01} & \rho_{10,10} & \rho_{10,11} \\
\rho_{11,00} & \rho_{11,01} & \rho_{11,10} & \rho_{11,11} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Consider the following three determinants:

$$ W_2 = \begin{vmatrix}
\rho_{00,00} & \rho_{01,00} \\
\rho_{00,01} & \rho_{01,01} \\
\end{vmatrix} $$

$$W_3 = \begin{vmatrix}
\rho_{00,00} & \rho_{01,00} & \rho_{00,10} \\
\rho_{00,01} & \rho_{01,01} & \rho_{00,11}  \\
\rho_{10,00} & \rho_{11,00} & \rho_{10,10}  \\
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$W_4 = \begin{vmatrix}
\rho_{00,00} & \rho_{01,00} & \rho_{00,10} & \rho_{01,10} \\
\rho_{00,01} & \rho_{01,01} & \rho_{00,11} & \rho_{01,11}\\
\rho_{10,00} & \rho_{11,00} & \rho_{10,10} & \rho_{11,10}\\
\rho_{10,01} & \rho_{11,01} & \rho_{10,11} & \rho_{11,11}\\
\end{vmatrix}$$

Notice that $W_4$ is the determinant of the partial transpose of the matrix and $W_3$ and $W_2$ are the first 3*3 and 2*2 elements of the partial transpose.

The condition is if $W_2 \geq 0$ and ($W_3 < 0$ or $W_4 < 0$), then the state is entangled. If not, it is separable.

How are these two equivalent?

Also, can this method be extended to ensure the smallest eigenvalue is greater than any $x$, where $x$ is not necessarily 0?

Comment: You're stating this as an equivalent to the standard formulation. What's your source?

Comment: Incidentally, the fact that you've diagonalised $W_4$ does not mean that you've diagonalised $W_2$ or $W_3$. For example, you cannot just take a diagonal density matrix - obviously it's not entangled and therefore certainly should not fit the criteria.

Comment: @DaftWullie, added source, and removed the diagonalisation. My bad. A diagonal density matrix in a separable basis should be separable, and is therefore correctly identified by this criteria, right?

Answer (score 4):

This is called [Sylvester's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion). There's plenty of information available once you have the name. The linked wikipedia article contains a proof.

Strictly, Sylvester's Criterion requires that $W_2,W_3,W_4> 0$ for the state to be positive under the partial transpose. However, for a density matrix, $W_2$ is always positive semi-definite. This is because you could certainly define a density matrix of the form
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\rho_{00,00} & \rho_{01,00} & 0 & 0 \\
\rho_{00,10} & \rho_{01,01} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
$$
up to some rescaling. This has the same determinant $W_2$ but is separable,
 and hence unaffected by the partial transpose.
Hence, non-positivity is determined by looking at a violation caused by $W_3$ or $W_4$.

I agree with a query in the comments that it is not immediately obvious that it is relevant for detecting negativity (I will continue to think about it...). If it *is* a problem, we should be able to come up with a counter-example.

The method is easily extended to any smallest eigenvalue. Simply reduce the matrix by $x$ times the appropriately sized identity matrix, shifting the min eigenvalue from $x$  to 0.

Comment: According to the Wikipedia page, a Hermitian matrix is positive semi-definite if all principal minors are non-negative, not just the leading ones. If we look at a density matrix, there are 10 principal minors, 4 1*1 ones, but they're all $\geq$ 0, 3 2*2 ones, the extremes of which are $\geq$ 0 , 2 3*3 ones, and 1 4*4 one. 

By this condition, if we want to find whether the matrix is entangled, we need to check if any of the 4 determinants (1 2*2, 2 3*3 and 1 4*4 are negative), right? This isn't equal to the condition given in the paper?